# How to solve when shows - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in react project?

Tags: reactjs

I have tried to resolve the problems but cant find the solution where the main bug is.Below are result and code.
[image]
import React from "react";
import Ingredient from "../Ingredient/Ingredient";
import './Burger.css';

```
    const Burger = (props) => {
    
      let ingredientArr = props.ingredients.map(item => {
        let amountArr = [...Array(item.amount).keys()]
          return amountArr.map( _ => {
            return <Ingredient type= {item.type} key= {Math.random()} />
          })
      })
```

Comment: `ingredients` shouldn't be undefined when be passed through props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your props like this

```
const Burger = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
      let ingredientArr = props.ingredients.map(item => {
        let amountArr = [...Array(item.amount).keys()]
          return amountArr.map( _ => {
            return <Ingredient type= {item.type} key= {Math.random()} />
          })
      })
```

Currently, your props doesn't contain ingredients. You can put a check like

```
if(props.ingredients){
let ingredientArr = props.ingredients.map(item => {
            let amountArr = [...Array(item.amount).keys()]
              return amountArr.map( _ => {
                return <Ingredient type= {item.type} key= {Math.random()} />
              })
          })

}
```

Comment: Thank you. i will try to solve and come back to you again.